# Transaction Failure in payment gateway Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I have installed authorize.net sdk(PHP) and changed config file. I am running the sample app that comes along with the bundle.

When I proceed with the payment, the transaction fails and responses below error

"We're sorry, but we can't process your order at this time due to the following error:

The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.
response code   3
response reason code    13"

Answer (score 0):

Naturally you need to verify your login credentials are correct. Also, make sure you are using the right server. You can use the production server or development server for testing. If you mix up your credentials that will cause this also.